# .NET MVC Timed Event on Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timer

I'm in need of some guidance as to how to proceed with my application.  I have a controller action that uses [HttpGet] & [HttpPost] to look up a question (and verify the answer on the POST) from a XML document sent via a web service.

The action posts back every time a question is answered, and my problem exists in attempting to time this series of post-back events.

My ultimate goal is to create a timer whose duration is based on a value in my XML.  The timer will be called once when the [HttpGet] initially loads and persist until the duration expires where it will then navigate to another action within my application.

I have considered using Jquery timers, and having the post-backs utilize partial AJAX requests but I would prefer to keep this functionality entirely server-side.

Could you recommend any suggestions and/or sample code?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I stuck with calling JQuery Timers at the initial page load, and then use AJAX partial view postbacks to loop through my XML (via a controller action) whilst maintaining the timer from outside the partial.